# retrofit 2 post Multipart Json with name

Tags: android, json, post, multipart, retrofit2

I am trying to post via retrofit 2, coordinates, example:

name="geo" {"date":"2016-03-28 18:15:22","lat":65.9667,"long":-18.5333}

can you help me please. I have,
Model:

```
public class LocationCoordinatesEntity{

@SerializedName("long")
@Expose
private Double longitude;

@SerializedName("lat")
@Expose
private Double latitude;

@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private Date date;

public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public LocationCoordinatesEntity(Double longitude, Double latitude, Long date){
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.date = new Date(date);
} }
```

and

```
@Multipart
@POST("setgeojson")
Observable<Void> setgeoMultipart(@Part("geo") String geo);
```

and

```
  Observable<Void> sendMultipartObservable = apiInterface.setgeoMultipart(gson.toJson(coordinatesEntity));
```

When I am tieng to post this i get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSON must start with an array or an object.
```

Comment: why you are using `multipart` what is purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to post a string instead of the json object.

Change this:

```
apiInterface.setgeoMultipart(coordinatesEntity);
```

And change this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("setgeojson")
Observable<Void> setgeoMultipart(@Part("geo") LocationCoordinatesEntity geo);
```

Comment: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.
and in this case i will have only Json without key "geo"

Comment: My bad, try `setgeoMultipart(@Part("geo") LocationCoordinatesEntity geo)`

Comment: thank you, this works, but what if I need to send List of coordinatesEntity the same way?

Comment: I've not tried it but you can try `List<LocationCoordinatesEntity> geo ` or something like that.

Comment: this will post them like an independent Json objects separately, but not like JsonArray

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to do this (This will combine 2 JSON objects into 1 when retrofit will do the Http post):

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("obj1name", someObject1);
map.put("obj2name", someObject2);
somePostCall(map);
```

And the interface call should look like:

```
@POST("some/url/to/post")
Call<SomeType> somePostCall(
        @Body HashMap combinedObject
);
```